# Compact Outlook .OST file using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have multiple VDI running on Outlook 2010, is there a way to compact the .OST file using PowerShell without user's manual compact action?

I tried to search cmdlets but couldnt find one. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: There's no commandline/comobject-solution to compact OST AFAIK. Why are you using mailbox caching on a VDI in the first place? Is your internet connection for the VDI-servers slow and unstable? If not, I'd simply disable caching using GPO to save the space.

Comment: Yes. It has been set up in that way. Internet connection is OK, no issues with that. Disabling the GPO is not an option. I'm just looking at the options that i have in order to compact that ost files. That's fine & thanks for the input.

Comment: Even if it was decided a long time ago it can probably be changed if you have good reasons. It sounds like you're having problems with the size (why else compact it?) and the best way to compact is to remove it in the first place. Your choice of course.

Comment: You should revisit the GPO setting again, @MuthukumaranThavarajoo.  The systems in question are VDI, by it's definition, it runs on a server somewhere which should always have connection to a mail server.  Caching on VDI is just wasting disk space and reduces your VM Density.